# How can I link an angular .ts file to an already created html page?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on a website and I am completely done with the html pages but I need to use angular in order to complete the website.
I have only ever used angular while working on ionic apps and I’m aware that the CLI generates the html, ts and css pages but I was wondering if it’s possible to link the html pages I’ve already created to the ts file?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "right" answer to this question, but there are two ways to go about this.

**Break down the HTML into components**

Honestly, this is the preferred way. Break down your page into reuseable components and compose them like you would do in an ionic app.

**Enhance the existing HTML**

You could put your HTML into your index.html, or better, your app.component.html, and only extract components where you need to make your html dynamic. This is not really the angular way though and will be difficult to maintain on the long run - but technically, this works.